# Upload images to fixed positions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, upload

I really need your help. I would like to ask if it is possible using flash to upload multiple images to particular positions. For example, I have a target that is called "people" and when someone uploads an image that is called "people" the image will be placed on that target.

I apologize for my English.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to also store some information about the image uploaded, in order to use that when you retrieve/use it?

Easy-cheezy way is to store a 'keyword' in the filename of the uploaded image.
e.g.
for image01.jpg uploaded that belongs to "people", upload that as, or rename when it is on the server as image01_people.jpg, then in flash when you load the image just do a split() for the "_" so you can get to the tag and isolate "people" out of image01_people.jpg.

A better way would be to save some information about the uploaded image (like category) either in a simple table in a database, or at least in a CSV text file or xml file.

HTH,
George